# mysql сортировка по проценту разности между полями

Tags: php, mysql, order

Есть 2 поля — `price` и `saleprice`, сортировка по скидке идет в виде `order by` (price-saleprice). Так вот, как сделать сортировку по проценту разнице скидки, чтобы товары шли как -50%, -40%, -30% и так далее, а не по разнице между полями.

Comment: А процент от чего, что принимается за 100% ? Если price - то видимо `sileprice / price`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что по стандартной пропорции.

```
price - 100%
saleprice - x%
x = saleprice * 100 / price
```

Ввиду того, что Вам нужна разница, то сравнивать надо следующую величину:

```
y = 100 - saleprice * 100 / price
```

Таким образом, если price = 70, saleprice = 150, то, подставляя получаем -114%